# how extract values from multidimensional array

Tags: multidimensional-array

I have this multidimensional array:

```
Array
(
    [car] => Array
        (
            [responsecode] => 200
            [ford] => Array
                (
                    [start] => 0
                    [count] => 20
                    [model] => 972000
                    [results] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [date] => 
                                    [clickurl] => xx
                                    [url] => xx
                                    [dispurl] => xx
                                    [title] => xx
                                    [abstract] => xx
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [date] => 
                                    [clickurl] => xx
                                    [url] => xx
                                    [dispurl] => xx
                                    [title] => Txx
                                    [abstract] => xx
                                )
```

I need retrieve value from **[model]** (972000)

Its really hard for me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have your array assigned to a variable say $arry then it would be

```
$arry['car']['ford']['model']
```

there are other techniques to get the 'model' from every 'car' in an array, is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    42    => 24,
    "multi" => array(
             "dimensional" => array(
                     "array" => "foo"
         )
    )
);

var_dump($array["foo"]);
var_dump($array[42]);
var_dump($array["multi"]["dimensional"]["array"]);
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php